# How to create Archive build with Specific / Native Only Architecture for Intel based Latest Mac OS

Tags: swift, xcode, intel, macos-monterey, xcode-archive

Recently i was working on a project (macOs application) for intel chip based for Latest macOS.

My working environment:

Xcode: Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Mac OS: Monterey
Version: 12.5 (21G72)
Chip: Intel

The problem i am having is my code runs from Xcode without any issue. But when i try to archive it fails to create archive with an error because it has many codes that only run on intel based mac os and it's trying to create a universal app for both intel chip as well as apple with standard architecture.

So my question is how i can change the build Architecture for my project in order to run on apple MacOs based On intel Chip only?

I know it can be changed from the "Build setting -> Architectures"  but i could not find what to change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Archive uses the Release build configuration when building. Setting the Build Active Architecture Only setting to YES for release builds will create an Intel-only archive.

But you should fix the issue you're having creating universal archives. More and more people are buying Apple Silicon Macs and want apps that run natively on Apple Silicon. You should be able to create a universal archive from an Intel Mac without errors.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I wanted to create an intel-only archive anyway.. cause that was the job description. In order to do so you not only have to set the build active Architecture only = yes but also you have to set the Architecture  = native architecture from Standard architecture. That's what i have found out and now I can build the archive without any issue only for intel based mac pc.